# When i runserver in Django it not running as 127.0.0.0:8000 instead of this it is going to 127.0.0.0:8000/application

Tags: django, django-urls

when i runserver from different projects also it is redirecting to 127.0.0.0:8000/application. I tried by creating new project but no use. i am getting same. Actually this started happening when i downloaded a project from github after that i am facing this problem.

Comment: Show your `views.py` and `urls.py`

Comment: Every project of Django, if you run will be accessible using URL `127.0.0.1:8000` by default... not sure what is your question

Answer (score 1):

It is due to browser cache. Try to clear your browser's data and cache and see if it works fine.